# How do I get the original values of in an Update SQL Trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm not very familiar with triggers so thank you for your patience.

I have a database table with four columns for user text input and just four date columns showing when the user text input was last changed. What I want the trigger to do is to compare the original and new values of the user text input columns and if they are different update the date column with getdate(). I don't know how to do this. The code I wrote can't get the pre-update value of the field so it can't be compared to the post-update value. Does anyone know how to do it?

(Normally I would do this in a stored procedure. However this database table can also be directly edited by an Access database and we can't convert those changes to use the stored procedure. This only leaves us with using a trigger.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sql server there are two special tables availble in the trigger called inserted and deleted. Same structure as the table on which the trigger is implemented. 
inserted has the new versions, deleted the old.